# What is the difference between patents and research articles?

Tags: publications, intellectual-property, patents

Both patents and research papers are the original works of the author which are never attempted by any other person in academic domain. So what distinguishes a patent from a research article ?

Comment: They have less in common than they have differences. The main differences are probably the goal (dissemination of knowledge vs establishing intellectual property) and the requirements (further science and pass peer review vs any novelty and convince a bureaucrat).

Comment: What is the difference between horses and spiders?

Comment: One is practically a contract, following legally strictly defined content and language, while the other is about disseminating information to a community, doing so with much different content and language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does applying for a patent first make it more difficult to publish (or vice versa)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20245/does-applying-for-a-patent-first-make-it-more-difficult-to-publish-or-vice-vers)

Answer (score 2):

Patents are for protecting intellectual property. Papers are for the dissemination of research results.